# cms:out escapeXml="false": prevent <br> in multi line input

Tags: jsp, content-management-system, magnolia

Using `cms:out escapeXml="false"` in a Magnolia jsp, outputs a `<br>` anywhere, where a line break is in the input string.

In the jsp, the code is:
`<cms:out nodeDataName="plainHtml" escapeXml="false" />`
`plainHtml` is set with a `controlType`: `edit`, `type`: `String`.

Is it possible to prevent the output of `<br>` anywhere, where a line break is in the input string?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "lineBreak" parameter that you can set to any string you like. See [Magnolia taglib documentation](http://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/sites/magnolia.public.sites/ref/4.4/magnolia-taglib-cms/tagreference.html#cms%3aout) for more information.

Comment: That sounds reasonable--I will give it a try!

Comment: -> That's it. I really didn't see that. Thanks for your help!